# Gnuplot equation of state fitting loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, gnuplot, equation

I am trying to make a script to fit 50 files of free energy vs volume using the Birch Murnaghan equation of state. I'm fitting for 3 parameters, emin, v0 and k0. I can't seem to get a loop to work which would loop over each file fitting it and then making 50 new files of the three fitting parameters.

```
   birch(x) = emin + 1.5*v0*k0/1602 * ( 0.75*(1+2*xsi)*(v0/x)**(4.0/3.0) \
-xsi/2*(v0/x)**2 - 3.0/2.0*(1+xsi)*(v0/x)**(2.0/3.0) + 0.5*(xsi+1.5) )
emin=-8
k0=2000
v0=10
xsi=0

do for [n=100:5000:100]{
   file = sprintf('free.%.f',n)
   fit birch(x) file via emin,v0,k0
   A = A.sprintf(%f,emin)
   B = B.sprintf(%f,v0)
   C = C.sprintf(%f,k0)
}
```

'''
The data is saved in files going free.100 free.200 and so on till free.5000, does anybody know how I could do this I only really want to make a script so I don't have to manually fit all the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(While I was coding @maij already posted an answer. I'll nevertheless post my example)

You don't specify how the output files should look like.
In order to write something to a file in gnuplot you can use `set print <FILE>`, check `help set print`.
Check the following example:

**Code:**

```
### store fitting parameters into file
reset session

myFile(n)  = sprintf("free.%d",n)
myParamFile(n) = sprintf("free.%d.param",n)
set key left

# create some test data in files
do for [i=100:600:100] {
    set print myFile(i)
        m = int(rand(0)*10)+0.1
        c = int(rand(0)*10)
        do for [j=1:20] {
            print sprintf("%g %g",j, m*j + 5*m*rand(0) + c)
        }
    set print
}

set fit brief nolog
f(x) = a*x + b

set multiplot layout 3,2
    do for [i=100:600:100] {
        fit f(x) myFile(i) via a,b
        set print myParamFile(i)
            print sprintf("a = %g",a)
            print sprintf("b = %g",b)
        set print
        plot myFile(i) w p pt 7 lc "blue" ti myFile(i), \
             f(x) w l lc "red" 
    }
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

`free.100.param`

```
a = 3.29395
b = 8.13496
```

`free.200.param`

```
a = 1.99086
b = 7.94427
```

`free.300.param`

```
a = 2.11392
b = 12.3286
```

`free.400.param`

```
a = 3.97004
b = 13.3108
```

`free.500.param`

```
a = 7.60895
b = 15.8168
```

`free.600.param`

```
a = 0.0982883
b = 8.2272
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `set print` command to specify the output file for the print command.

```
do for [n=100:5000:100]{
   input_file = sprintf('free.%.f',n)
   fit birch(x) input_file via emin,v0,k0

   # set output file for print command
   output_file = sprintf('free.%.f.result', n)
   set print output_file

   # write output, choose format as you need it
   print(input_file)
   output_line = sprintf('emin = %f', emin)
   print(output_line)
   print(v0)
   print(k0)
}
```

This will create 50 output files free.100.result, ... in the current directory. The output of the following `print` command goes to these files.

**Update**

For printing values of a function, you can use two approaches:

```
do for [n=100:5000:100]{

   ...
   fit ...
   ...

   # with 'set table' command into a separate file
   table_file = sprintf('free.%.f.table', n)
   set table table_file
   set xrange [6:7]
   set samples 11
   plot birch(x)
   unset table

   # print manually into normal print output file
   # please note, step size must be an integer
   do for [i = 60:70:1] { 
      x = i/10.0
      output_line = sprintf("%f  %f", x, birch(x))
      print(output_line)
   } 
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for the answer that really helped. Now If I fit some function to another free energy plot using a similar script.  How could I take the derivative of the fit with respect to volume and record the value for the derivative against the respective volume.

Comment: ''                                                                                                                                        
F(x) = a + b*x + c*x**2 + d*x**3
dF(x)= b + 2*c*x + 3*d*x**2
do for [n=100:5000:100]{
   input_file = sprintf('Gibbs.%.f',n)
   fit F(x) input_file via a,b,c,d
# set output file for print command
   output_file = sprintf('Pressure.%.f.result', n)
   set print output_file      x=6:7:(0.1) 
  print(-dF(x))
}
''

Comment: So I would like to record this dF(x) derivative  against  the x values ranging 6-7 in increments of 0.1.

Comment: @GeorgeBeasley See update. Please note that the step size in a `for` expression must be an integer  number. (And you have to replace birch(x) by its derivative.)